# Logarithm limit, almost Riemann sum $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\log\frac kn=-1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, summation, logarithms

I want to show that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\log\frac{k}{n}=-1$.

Now I could say that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\log\frac{k}{n}=\int_0^1\log xdx$ but I can't as $\log x$ isn't uniform continuous on the given interval. I found a way which goes over the convergence radius of a power series connected to the term in the limit, but I think one could just make the argument with the riemann sum work somehow?!

Comment: I do not know if it is a way to use Riemann sums, but note that your sum is $S_n=(\log n!-n\log n)/n$, so Stirling's formula can be a way to the solution....

Comment: Thanks, but I really want to know if the 'riemann sum way' would work somehow, as the integral has the same value!

Comment: Why is this 'almost' Riemann sum; isn't it usually solved using this very method?

Comment: @StubbornAtom What do you mean? I thought you can only go over to the integral in case the function is uniform continuous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Draw the graph of $\log x$ and see that the sum $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n}\log(k/n)$ represents the sum of the area of boxes "under" the graph of $\log x$. Then try to estimate the error between the sum and $\int_{1/n}^1 \log x dx$ by finding another sum that represents the area of boxes that **cover** the graph of $\log x$ from $1/n$ to $1$. E.g. for the interval $[(n-1)/n, 1]$ do not use a box of height $0$ (as is used in your sum), but use a box of height $\log((n-1)/n)$.

Answer (score 6):

Claim: If $f$ is monotone on $(0,1],$ and the improper integral $\int_0^1 f$ converges, then

$$\int_0^1 f = \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}f(k/n)(1/n).$$

Proof: WLOG $f\ge 0$ and $f$ is decreasing. Then

$$\int_{1/n}^1 f \le \sum_{k=1}^{n}f(k/n)(1/n) \le \int_0^1 f.$$

This follows by staring down areas of rectangles and using the fact that $f$ is nonnegative and decreasing. The result follows by letting $n\to \infty$ and using the squeeze theorem.

In our problem we have $f(x) = \ln x.$ So $f$ is monotone and the convergence of $\int_a^1 \ln x\, dx$ to $-1$ as $a\to 0^+$ follows from the fact that $a\ln a \to 0.$ Therefore the desired limit follows from the claim.

Comment: (+1) Clear, Concise, Correct.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually surprisingly one quite simple way to find the limit in this particular case using L'Hospitals.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n \log(\frac{k}{n})}{n} = -\frac{\infty}{\infty}$$

As you can see this is already in L'hospitals format.
Taking the derivative of the top and bottom to find the limit becomes.
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n -\frac{1}{n}}{1}$$

And because the Sum goes through the sum 1 to n times (n times) so it will add $$-\frac{1}{n}$$ n times. So the limit becomes $$\lim_{n\to\infty} n(-\frac{1}{n}) = -1$$
From this you can prove that the limit is equal to -1.

Comment: This is fatally flawed logic.